# <div> block drops out of a <p> block

Tags: html, css

Hi have a Paragraph block with the following style applied:

```
form.filters p {
    clear:both;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
```

INSIDE the Paragragn, I have a Div with the following style:

```
form.filters .inputHolder {
    float:left;
}
```

When viewing the rendered page, the DIV seems to sit under the P, and when viewing the code in Chrome, the DIV acually is siting below the P..

Source Code:

```
<p>some stuff
  <div>more stuff<div>
</p>
```

Viewed in Chrome:

```
<p>some stuff</p>
<div>more stuff<div>
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening and what I can do to resolve this?

Many Thanks

Comment: `div`s can not be put inside `p`s. Use `span` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div>`s aren't allowed in `<p>`s. The HTML parser, when it sees the `<div>` tag, automatically closes the `<p>` element.

Use a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`.

Comment: Perfect.. makes sense.. I changed to a Span and included a break at the bottom and all worked fine.. Thanks Alohci!!

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec the `<p>` element cannot contain `"block-level elements (including P itself)"`. My guess is Chrome is just trying to be helpful here.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1